# How to return a String from a textfield when button is pressed?

Tags: java

I want to return a string `fileName` from the `enterFileName` textfield when I press the `saveFileNameBtn` button. I tried getting the text in an `inline action listener method` but when I do that the variable is out of scope when I try to return it.

```
String getSaveFileName()
{
    JFrame enterFileNameWin = new JFrame();
    JPanel fileNameP = new JPanel();
    enterFileNameWin.add(fileNameP);
    JLabel fileNamePrompt = new JLabel("Enter a name for the file");
    TextField enterFileName = new TextField(20);
    JButton saveFileNameBtn = new JButton("Save");

    fileNameP.add(fileNamePrompt);
    fileNameP.add(enterFileName);
    fileNameP.add(saveFileNameBtn);

    enterFileNameWin.setVisible(true);
    enterFileNameWin.setSize(300, 100);

    String fileName = enterFileName.getText();
    fileName = fileName + ".dat";

    saveFileNameBtn.addActionListener((ActionListener) this);

    return fileName;
}
```

This doesn't work because fileName is out of scope and cannot be returned.

```
    String getSaveFileName()
{
    JFrame enterFileNameWin = new JFrame();
    JPanel fileNameP = new JPanel();
    enterFileNameWin.add(fileNameP);
    JLabel fileNamePrompt = new JLabel("Enter a name for the file");
    TextField enterFileName = new TextField(20);
    JButton saveFileNameBtn = new JButton("Save");

    fileNameP.add(fileNamePrompt);
    fileNameP.add(enterFileName);
    fileNameP.add(saveFileNameBtn);

    enterFileNameWin.setVisible(true);
    enterFileNameWin.setSize(300, 100);

    saveFileNameBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            String fileName = enterFileName.getText();
            fileName = fileName + ".dat";

        }
    });
    return fileName;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
saveFileNameBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
      String textFieldValue = enterFileName.getText();
      // call another function or do some operations
   }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define the `fileName` variable outside of the ActionListener class and then reference it using the syntax `OuterclassName.this`. Since I don't know what the name of your class is, replace `Outerclass` with that name.

```
String getSaveFileName() {
    //your other code...
    String fileName;
    saveFileNameBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
            Outerclass.this.fileName = enterFileName.getText();
        }
    });
    return fileName;
}
```

If you are using Java 8, you could even simplify the code further using Lambda expressions for the Anonymous ActionListener class.

```
String getSaveFileName() {
    //your other code...
    String fileName;
    saveFileNameBtn.addActionListener( e->{ Outerclass.this.fileName = enterFileName.getText(); });

    return fileName;
}
```

A similar example can be found in this post: (ignoring the `final` issue) [Accessing Variable within JButton ActionListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19228436/accessing-variable-within-jbutton-actionlistener)