# I want to use a variable outside of "public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {}"

Tags: java

I need to create a GUI and enter the height and width there, click on the button and a new window will start with these heights and widths. Аt the moment I have variable values width and height  ​​which are set in public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {} and I want to use them to transfer the values ​​for a new window. I came to the conclusion that it is necessary either to pull values ​​from the JTextField itself or the way that I want to implement

```
public class Form extends JFrame implements Runnable {
    //private int w= 1280;
    //private int h=768;
    public int wt;
    public int ht;
    public void Okno() {

        JFrame win1 = new JFrame("Evolution.IO");       
        win1.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        win1.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        win1.setSize(470, 400);

        JPanel pane = new JPanel();
        pane.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        JTextField txtField = new JTextField(5);
        JTextField txtField2 = new JTextField(5);
        JLabel weightL = new JLabel("Weight: ");
        JLabel highL = new JLabel("High: ");
        pane.add(weightL);
        pane.add(txtField);
        pane.add(highL);
        pane.add(txtField2);

        JButton btn = new JButton("Начать симуляцию");
        btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {


            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                wt = Integer.parseInt(txtField.getText());
                ht = Integer.parseInt(txtField2.getText());
                if (!(txtField==null)) {
                    Form f = new Form();
                    new Thread(f).start();
                    win1.getDefaultCloseOperation();
                }
            }
        });
        pane.add(btn);
        win1.add(pane);
        win1.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        win1.setVisible(true);
    }
    //THIS DOESNT WORK#
//  public int w1() {
//        return this.wt;
//     }
//  public int h1() {
//        return this.ht;
//     }

    private final int FRAMES_TOTAL = 100000;
    private final int SKIP_FRAMES = 10;

    private final Color BG = new Color(200, 200, 200, 255);
    private final Color BLUE = new Color(150, 160, 255, 255);
    private final Color RED = new Color(255, 100, 120, 255);
    private BufferedImage buf = new BufferedImage(w1(), h1(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    private BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(w1(), h1(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    private BufferedImage graph = new BufferedImage(w1(), h1(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
//no longer needed
```

Comment: Would you like to create a variable inside `actionPerformed` method and make it available to outer scope? If yes check this --> https://stackoverflow.com/a/19228547/3881354 might be helpful

Comment: thank you, a will see it later, I hope it will be helpful :D